# GetSecret from Azure Vault throwing NullReferenceException when trying to connect

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I have the following issue:

I'm trying to connect to Azure Vault using a certificate credential.

When trying to read a secret, I get `AuthenticationFailedException` with an internal `NullReferenceException`.

For brevity I'm only including the stack trace for the NullReferenceException:

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Azure.Identity.AadIdentityClient.CreateClientAssertionJWT(string, string, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2)
    Azure.Identity.AadIdentityClient.CreateClientCertificateAuthRequest(string, string, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2, string[])
    Azure.Identity.AadIdentityClient.Authenticate(string, string, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2, string[], System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    Azure.Identity.ClientCertificateCredential.GetToken(Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
```

The code:

```
            string keyVaultUrl = "https://somevault.vault.azure.net/";
            var clientId = "<Application (client) ID>";
            var tenantId = "<Directory (tenant) ID>";
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"someCerFile.cer");
            ClientCertificateCredential certificateCreadential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientCertificate);
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), certificateCreadential);
            var secret = client.GetSecret("Password"); //This line throws the exception
```

Vault configuration is done according to the steps outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the PrivateKey is hydrated?

X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"someCerFile.cer");

if (null == clientCertificate)
{
     throw new ArithmeticException("clientCertificate is null");
}
{
    if (null == clientCertificate.PrivateKey)
 {
      throw new ArithmeticException("PrivateKey is null");
 }
}

Comment: Ultimately, I would put try/catch around each object creation (skip the basic strings of course).....and then verify each "piece"...one by one.....to help find the culprit.  then I'd look through the source : https://github.com/hidayath-ispace/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/af976ca48a4a2f029263db101ea0ab96488a3aaa/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/ClientCertificateCredential.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the exception is not very helpful. However, I believe the issue here is you need to give a X509Certificate2 has the private key so the `ClientCertificateCredential` can sign the client assertion. The `.cer` file is only the public portion of the certificate. You will need to supply a `.pfx`  file which contains both the certificate and the private key as well.